# java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format ... PublicKey error

Tags: java, spring, oauth, jwt, java-security

i know there are multiple questions, but none have seem to adapt to what i need.

I need to validate a JWT token, i only have the PublicKey (which is fine as with that i can validate the sign of jwt.

Code is as follow.

First we have publicKey

```
private static final String publicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA88aLoh5l9W9UY3Hb+YGU\r\n"
            + "ZQBwVWuNTNpF5nm9uU+MqmB7EUmTYdD4Jk09zjBUutnggY10Jbjxdrv09HnHrqbj\r\n"
            + "+hyOyIXgSsVIK5bGZVHKLJzzZmWgn0QgcEXzR97J47MFeWkn0tEgDlP8LEMZE7ix\r\n"
            + "9WgoJHGGtUaQV5MM3U9S13zyRmaYekCVfLh2REHevb1aHgDReCLx92ZIdc9ldE9g\r\n"
            + "99v87E5zNKSv3AI8EVRt/Tpjfyuk7XTEqY6pz83tCfy1uch8NihhVjY8O2J3pilP\r\n"
            + "VW/L83GMJ5Shea0mE2Dq9Gh4lrVvAy+OHkarwGgdlYLwy1Dmof2SYCCq2SJyv5ZR\r\n"
            + "fwIDAQAB";
```

Then inside a method we got

```
JWTVerifier verifierToken =  JWT.require(Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) getPublicFederaKey(), null)).build();
        DecodedJWT decodeJwt = verifierToken.verify(token);
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        String codiceFiscale = decodeJwt.getClaim("CODICEFISCALE").asString();
        System.err.println("CODICE FISCALE: "+codiceFiscale);
        
        if (decodeJwt.getExpiresAt().before(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Expired token!");
        }
```

If you see on verifiedToken it makes reference to getPublicFederaKey();

```
private PublicKey getPublicFederaKey() throws CustomException {
        PublicKey key = null;
        

        try{
            
        String keyTrimmed = publicKey.trim().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
        System.err.println(keyTrimmed);
        int stringLength = keyTrimmed.length(); //392
        String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(publicKey.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] hexedPublicKey = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexString);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(hexedPublicKey);

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        key = kf.generatePublic(keySpecX509);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return key;
        }
```

I saw an answer here and tried the hexParsing directly with the String but gave me error of illegal character present for hex or sth like that (i think its because it has a-f characters) so i guessed ok, its because it is waiting for a hex instead of raw String.

Then before i tried with Base64 something similar to this

```
rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pkey.getBytes());
PublicKey pk = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
```

Then at the end as you can see i am triying to replicate "Duncan Jones" response to no avail.

[java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format on generating RSA public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622894/java-security-invalidkeyexception-invalid-key-format-on-generating-rsa-public-k)

In any case what i need is the String publicKey (i cut the ----BEGIN---- -----END----), to be transformed to java.security.PublicKey to then be cast to java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At the end this worked.

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(keyTrimmed.getBytes());
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509B = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKey generatePublic = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpecX509B);
```

Notice the difference on the decoder...

Package java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder();

And i pass the string.getBytes() raw, without a previous Base64 encode

Important lesson, get the correct documentation from API Provider.

Just a bit of info from the javadocs

public class Base64
extends Object

This class consists exclusively of static methods for obtaining encoders and decoders for the Base64 encoding scheme. The implementation of this class supports the following types of Base64as specified in RFC 4648 and RFC 2045. •Basic
Uses "The Base64 Alphabet" as specified in Table 1 of RFC 4648 and RFC 2045 for encoding and decoding operation. The encoder does not add any line feed (line separator)character. The decoder rejects data that contains characters outside the base64 alphabet.

•URL and Filename safe
Uses the "URL and Filename safe Base64 Alphabet" as specified in Table 2 of RFC 4648 for encoding and decoding. The encoder does not add any line feed (line separator) character. The decoder rejects data that contains characters outside thebase64 alphabet.

•MIME
Uses "The Base64 Alphabet" as specified in Table 1 of RFC 2045 for encoding and decoding operation. The encoded output must be represented in lines of no more than 76 characters each and uses a carriage return '\r' followed immediately by a linefeed '\n' as the line separator. No line separator is added to the end of the encoded output. All line separators or other characters not found in the base64 alphabet table are ignored in decoding operation.

Seems the way my key was composed, it actually needed the \r and \n.